# Awk: subtract first line from all lines and multiply by factor

Tags: awk

I have a file that contains some numbers

```
$ cat file.dat
0.092593
0.048631
0.027957
0.030699
0.026250
0.038156
0.011823
0.013284
0.024529
0.022498
0.013217
0.007105
0.018916
0.014079
```

I want to subtract the first number from all other numbers, and then multiply the difference with 627.509. Expected output

```
$ cat newfile.dat
0.000000
-27.586551
-40.559672
-38.839042
-41.630830
-34.159707
-50.683902
-49.767111
-42.710773
-43.985243
-49.809154
-53.644489
-46.232981
-49.268242
```

Assuming I want to do this with awk, do I have to create a variable containing the first number before the awk statement, e.g.

```
factor=$(head -1 myfile.dat)
```

or can I do this completely with awk?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
awk 'NR == 1 {DELTA = $0} {$0 = ($0 - DELTA) * FAC; print}' FAC=627.509 file
```

Comment: This solution lacks the first result, which would be "0" (zero), which I also want (should have made that clearer, perhaps). Removing the second condition fixes it.

Comment: Rats - you're right. I dropped the `NR > 1` condition in my answer.

Comment: @Yoda: Use e.g. `printf "%.6f", $0` if you want higher precision

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
$ awk -v c=627.509 'NR==1 { b=$1 } { printf( "%0.6f\n", ( $1-b ) * c ) }' file.dat
0.000000
-27.586551
-40.559672
-38.839042
-41.630830
-34.159707
-50.683902
-49.767111
-42.710773
-43.985243
-49.809154
-53.644489
-46.232981
-49.268242
```